# cant play this video for splash android

Tags: android, splash-screen, android-videoview

Hi I set a video for splash screen and it shows on above android 4.4.4  but it is not show on android 4.4.2

**Here is my code **

```
  videoView = findViewById(R.id.videoView1);

    Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.splash);
    videoView.setVideoURI(video);
    videoView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
    videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.start();

     new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {




            startActivity(new Intent(SplshScreen.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    }, 1500);
```

**Errors on logcat :**

```
Activity.SplshScreen has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{9d069060 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-1026,318} that was originally added here
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:348)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
    at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:951)
    at android.widget.VideoView$5.onError(VideoView.java:515)
    at android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaPlayer.java:2248)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

thank in advance!

Comment: Do you get any error or stacktrace in logcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this snippet after `videoView.setVideoURI(video);`

```
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(this);
```

hope it works.